# Get CSS background to cover numerous divs

Tags: css, background, height, css-float

At the moment, I have two div tags which are set to "float:left;" I want to apply a background colour to both but each can vary in size dependent on the contents.
I have tried adding an extra div and just applying a background colour to it but there is no height?
Here is my test page: http://joshblease.co.uk/wp-content/themes/rounded/test.php

Thanks, Josh.

Comment: Which divs?  And do you mean color or background-image?

Comment: main and main2, you can see the colour of them bothon the page and it's just a colour "background-color:rgba(153,153,153,0.5);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I see.  You want the background to be a box around the extremes of the floated divs?

Parent divs by default do not expand to contain floated children.  There are a few workarounds to this:

- Set the parent div to have `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto`.
- Add an empty element after the parent (`#back`), and set it to `clear: both`.
- Use css to do the above automatically:

```
#back:after {
   content: ".";
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

Any of those should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following method avoids some issues that the `overflow` method can have in certain situations. This CSS uses your div ID based on my understanding of your test page markup.

```
#back {
    *zoom: 1;
}
#back:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

This is called clearing floats, or a "clearfix", in case you wish to search and read more.

Comment: I have read elsewhere that it is best to make the content non-empty and `visibility: hidden` for some browser.  No first-hand experience though.